# C: how would I write a search function to look for a match in a struct array, and return (print) the entire struct it matched?

Tags: c, search, loops, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define RECORDS 10
```

The function below is what I am asking for help with.

```
static char searchforRecordbystate(char input[3])
{
```

for / while /if loop

search struct array members

if a match is found

return (print) the entire struct where a match was found

```
    return 0;
}
```

Main function - first time ever using pointers, (xcode is not complaining with it set to be as strict as possible) but all of you are welcome to complain, especially if I am making a huge oversight.

```
int main() {
    typedef struct {
        char *firstName[RECORDS];
        char *lastName[RECORDS];
        char *street[RECORDS];
        char *city[RECORDS];
        char *state[RECORDS];
        int *zip[RECORDS];
        char *phone[RECORDS];
        int *accountId[RECORDS];
    } Customer ;    

    typedef int records;
    records i = 0;
```

array loop for data entry

```
    Customer custArray[RECORDS];
    printf("================================================================\n");
    for(i = 0; i < RECORDS; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter data for customer %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Enter firstname, last name, phone\n");
        scanf("%s %s %s", *custArray[i].firstName, *custArray[i].lastName, *custArray[i].phone);
        printf("Enter Address (Street City State ZIP)");
        scanf("%s %s %s*c %d", *custArray[i].street, *custArray[i].city, *custArray[i].state, *custArray[i].zip);
        break;
    }
    char input[3];
    printf("Enter in state to search for customer a customer record:\n");
    scanf("%s", input); 


    searchforRecordbystate(input);  

}
```

No error checking necessary, just trying to crawl into learning c at the moment. And there will not be duplicate data in the state member. Hope that makes this easier.

Comment: And what is your question? Perhaps, SO should implement a new rule/policy to disallow any question which does not have `?` in the post.

Comment: Sorry let me edit it. to be a little more clear.

Comment: So you basically want to loop over all the records and search for a particular state?

Comment: C: how would I write a search function to look for a match in a struct array and return (printf) the entire struct it matched?

Comment: You shouldn't put a typedef in the context of a function as it's very likely you need the datatype elsewhere (e.g. in your search function).

Comment: Your `Customer` structure doesn't look right. Does a single customer really need to have an array of names, an array of streets, an array of zip codes, etc?

Comment: @DevendraD.Chavan Yes. and print the record where the state matched.

Comment: So you want a code for that function ?

Comment: @Barmar Your correct. This is a oversight on my part. I have been focusing with this search function.

Comment: Just for clarification, `char *firstName[RECORDS]`, is this supposed to represent a single name or an array of names? I think you want it to refer to the former. If so, then it should be `char *firstName`.

Comment: @DevendraD.Chavan That was my point.

Comment: @DevendraD.Chavan  one name for one record. But an array of records.

Comment: Then you need to correct the `struct Customer`. It should be `char *firstName`, etc.

Comment: @DevendraD.Chavan; no, it should be `char firstName[32];` or some other size (bigger than 10).

Comment: I agree. It should be a fixed size array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually this decision depends on wheter you want to allocate the memory for firstName or not. Fixed sized fields (especially for names) are usually subject to be a pain sooner or later. Either because they waste memory or they lack of space for a name I want to add.

Comment: @DevendraD.Chavan cc to you too :-)

Comment: @junix: when someone is having problems of the type in the question, it is not time to bring in dynamic memory allocation.  Yes, it would be possible to use dynamic memory allocation — but not until fixed size arrays/strings in arrays of structures are handled comfortably.  At this stage, it is unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree your point with the simplification and because simplification often implies omitting of side effects, I always strongly vote to make at least a side note about possible issues with the simplification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how would I write a search function to look for a match in a struct
>   array and return (printf) the entire struct it matched?

1. Declare the struct datatype outside of the function so it's "visible" to the whole module.
2. Create a function that is able to pretty-print a struct:

   `void CustomerPrint(const Customer *toPrint) {
       ...
   }`
3. Create a search function that iterates through the array comparing given arguments:

   `Customer *CustomerFind(const char *name) {
   ...
   }`
4. Connect the two function blocks by calling `CustomerFind` and in case the result is not `NULL` call the `CustomerPrint` function.

Of course the interfaces are only proposal and are subject to be changed. If you've got any questions regarding the details of the proposal leave a comment, I'll explain it in great detail if you like.

**Additional thoughts**

While rereading my post I realized that some of my decisions I've made in above proposal need an explaination anyway:

In **CustomerPrint** the pointer taken is `const?  because this function is not going to modify any field of the struct. Therefore we tell the compiler that we are not going to change anything.

**CustomerFind** is expected to have arguments for all searchable fields. (So you are encouraged to extend the signature) I'd propose to take all the "compare" values by pointer and let the caller those pointers be `NULL` which are not relevant for the search. (e.g. if you have `name` and `city` you can leave `city` NULL in order to only search for the first occurence of `name`.

The function itself runs through the array of records and compares the fields that are not `NULL`. In case it finds one, it returns the pointer to that element (`return &(myRecords[n]);`). If the function comes to the end of the array, it will return `NULL` to indicate no record matched.

There is also a concept you can introduce if you want to have "search - search next" capabilities. Let me know if you are intrested in a concept for that too.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct {
    char firstName[NAMEMAX];
    char lastName[NAMXMAX];
    char street[STREETMAX];
    char city[CITYMAX];
    char state[STATEMAX];
    int  zip;
    char phone[PHONEMAX];
    int  accountId;
} Customer ;

Customer Customers[RECORDS];  

static int searchforRecordbystate(char input[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < RECORDS; i++) {
    if (strcmp(input, Customers[i].state) == 0) {
      printCustomer(Customers[i]);
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1; // Not found
}
```

Writing `printCustomer()` is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Do you pass the record to `printCustomer` by value intentionally? A bit inefficient isn't it?

Comment: @junix Yeah, wasn't worrying too much about that, just trying to get the general point across.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Given the OP is "just trying to crawl into learning c" I'd say it's curcial to give him careful crafted code (if any) taking care of the details too because it will be an example the OP is learing from. The risk of copying parts of the construction without thinking about the side effects is simply to high in my opinion to just take care of the "general point".

Comment: If you want to go all out and craft it nicely, post your own answer. I only have so much time. If I were doing it properly, `Customers` wouldn't be a global variable, either. And since it _is_ a global variable, `printCustomer()` could just take `i` as the parameter....

Comment: If I don't have the time to craft a post nicely, I don't post an answer. This because I don't think it helps if I post some not "nicely crafted" code which appears to be "copy pastable" to a beginner while bearing pitfalls not too obvious to him. But that's a different discussion. I brought up my point and that's all what I wanted to.

Comment: The code is decent, it's teaches him the fundamentals. It doesn't have to be perfect, professional quality to serve this purpose.

Comment: I disagree. It doesn't teach the fundamentals. It teaches a pattern which is possibly dangerous. And that's exactly my problem with it. But I don't want to steal your precious time. So instead of going on with this discussion I propose spend the time you want to spend for writing an answer to me with improving your "decent" example so the OP can learn something usable from it. (Because that's the only thing that really matters)

Comment: The guy doesn't even know how to write a structure properly. Anyway, if you can do better, post an answer instead of arguing with me. I'll happily upvote it.

Comment: As you might have noticed I even posted an answer before you posted yours. The thing I wanted to point out between the lines in my last comment was that your argument of having a lack of time to do it better somehow loses validity regading the time you spent arguing with me whether to improve the code you posted or not. (just to make that point clear for once) But you are right. We should stop the discussion here.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice that you were the one who posted the answer that doesn't contain any code. I guess that's the trivial way to avoid showing bad code....

Comment: Yeah, a very cheap try to bring this discussion on a personal level. Let me say I show code when it's necessary to show code. If you want to judge my code you can either read my answer and look what I want the OP to write or you can look at other answers of mine where I show "bad code". But anyway. your last answer just shows that any further comment is even more wasting of time than the one before. Have a nice day.