# If statement to print worker name

Tags: c++, c

I cant get my intended result I want my program to display can anyone help me. The program is to print the workers name who are listed in the struct and if you don't enter any of those names I should print worker name doesn't exist. Can someone tell me the code/ syntax to use

Here is what I have

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <conio.h>       
#include <string.h>

//Program Purpose: To accept a specific set of worker names and worker id number and accept the time they came to work and determine if they were early or late for the day.`

struct workers {
    char worker_name[10];
    int worker_id;
}   workers;

int main ()
{
    struct workers worker1; 
    struct workers worker2;

    strcpy (worker1.worker_name, "sean");
    worker1.worker_Id = 1234;
    strcpy (worker2.worker_name,"tajae");
    worker2.worker_Id = 7890;

    char worker_name [30];
    int Worker_Id;
    float Time_Arrived;
    float Minutes_Late;
    float Extra_Minutes;
    float Minutes_Early;
    float lunch_time;
    float Departure;

    printf("******************Produce Pro Time Management System********************\n\n");
    printf("Good morning. Welcome to Produce Pro, Hope you had a good nights rest and ready to have a successful day at work today.\n\n");
    printf("Please follow the instruction and answer with the required details\n");
    printf("Note brief: All time are in army hours\n\n");
    printf("Enter your Worker Name\n");

    scanf("%S",&worker_name[30]);

    if (worker_name= worker1,worker2) // this is the error in the program//
    {
        printf(&worker_name[30]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Worker Name doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

when i make a change the if statement and put

```
if (worker_name == worker1.worker_name || worker_name == worker2.worker_name)

{
printf("Welcome %s\n",worker_name);
}

else printf ("Worker Name doesn't exist\n");
```

worker doesn't eixt is what i get

Comment: You need to use string compare functions, like `strcmp` or to be safer `strncmp` with a limit of 10 since that is the max length of your string.

Comment: Indent 4 spaces (or select your code and push Ctrl-K) to format it. Do not use backticks for a code block.

Comment: Wait, it's not just `strcmp()` why are you doing this `Worker_name= worker1,worker2`???

Comment: @helpme . In the scanf you have to use Worker_name instead of Worker_name[10]); and instead of this statement if (Worker_name= worker1,worker2) you have to use  if ( strcmp( Worker_name, worker1,worker2 ) == 0 )

Comment: @iharob i dnt knw if statement for it so i used that

Comment: @barmar look at this program and see if u can fix the error pls

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to specify the Struct member in your If Condition if you are checking only the names? Please see below.

```
if (Worker_name == worker1.Worker_name || Worker_name == worker2.Worker_name)
{
    printf("Welcome %s\n",Worker_name);
}
```

or

```
if (strcmp(Worker_name,worker1.Worker_name) != 0 || strcmp(Worker_name,worker2.Worker_name) != 0)
{
    printf("Welcome %s\n",Worker_name);
}
```

Comment: Your second version is flawed. It uses the comma operator which will just throw away the first operand. You're only comparing against `worker2.Worker_name`.

Comment: this is right but it only print worker doesn't exits even if i put in the worker in the struct above @SaagarEliasJacky

Comment: What is `&Worker_name[10]` supposed to do?

Comment: thats the variable name

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this post, it's excatly the same problem with the answer to it:

[C: how would I write a search function to look for a match in a struct array, and return (print) the entire struct it matched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038035/c-how-would-i-write-a-search-function-to-look-for-a-match-in-a-struct-array-an)

Answer (score 0):

In C you can use `strcmp` to [compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) two null-terminated (!) byte strings lexicographically:

```
int err = strcmp(worker1,worker2);
if( err == 0))
    printf("ok,equal\n");
else if(err < 0)
    printf("[%s] precedes [%s]\n",worker1,worker2);
else if(err > 0)
    printf("[%s] follows [%s]\n",worker1,worker2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify scanf and printf statement this way:

```
scanf("%s",&Worker_name); //small letter 's'
```

or may be

```
scanf("%s",Worker_name);
```

and

```
printf("%s",Worker_name);
```

Hope this works..